# Run-Time Check Failure # 2 stack around "numbers" was corrupted

Tags: c++

The program executes and outputs the sorted array, but the program crashes. Please help me understand why and how to fix. Language and environment is c++ and VS on win7.

```
//test for ordering  numbers
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numbers[3];

    numbers[0] = 33;
    numbers[1] = 13;
    numbers[2] = 23;

    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] > numbers[i+1])
        {
            temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[i+1];
            numbers[i+1] = temp;    
            temp = 0;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in your `for` loop, when i is `2`, you are accessing `numbers[3]`, which is out of range access.

Comment: @lolando That's an answer. Post it.

Comment: Im in college at university of phoenix. I am beginning to lose faith and cannot keep more than 2-3 items in my mind at once. How do you know if you have what it takes to be a programmer, as I have focused on my teachings instead of programming and science. I am 25 and want to make it. I think I may be partially retarded though. I am confused right now about my abilities.

Comment: Thank you, I was accessing numbers [3], I needed to put i < 2, so the loop iterates 3 times. But, while i < 2, woulnd't the body execute twice? Is this due to only needing 2 iterations to sort 3 elements?

Comment: @Arden The problem is you're only swapping once, therefore it only needs to iterate twice instead of three times. Your sorting algorithm is ill-formed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, when `i` is 2, you are accessing `numbers[3]`, which is`out of range` access.

Please remember that when you declare `int numbers[3]`, you declare an array of 3 elements: `numbers[0]`, `numbers[1]`, and `numbers[2]`

Answer (score 0):

Typically a bubble sort looks like this:

```
for(int x=0; x< n; x++)
{
    for(int y=0; y< n-1; y++)
    {
        if(numbers[y]>numbers[y+1])
        {
            int temp = numbers[y+1];
            numbers[y+1] = numbers[y];
            numbers[y] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, only one swap was needed so you don't need the outer loop. However, in cases where multiple swaps are needed, you do need the outer loop. For example:

```
int numbers[7];

numbers[0] = 33;
numbers[1] = 53;
numbers[2] = 23;
numbers[3] = 4;
numbers[4] = 23;
numbers[5] = 10;
numbers[6] = 25;

int n = 7;

// Without this outer loop
// Output: 33 23 4 23 10 25 53
// With outer loop
// Output: 4 10 23 23 25 33 53
for (int x= 0; x < n; x++) {
    for(int y=0; y< n-1; y++)
    {
        if(numbers[y]>numbers[y+1])
        {
            int temp = numbers[y+1];
            numbers[y+1] = numbers[y];
            numbers[y] = temp;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    std::cout << numbers[i] << " ";
```

Comment: Thank you. The n-1 is hard to understand and I could not devise the double for loop until I worked it out on paper and checked it against your awesome reply. Does this mean my brain does not work for programming or do I need more practice and experience. I am in bachelor's program at university of phoenix software engineering. I just now became motivated.